# PHP, CodeIgniter, Sessions, and Tracking Id

Tags: php, ios, session

My website works fine for web browsers that go to my login-protected API pages. However I am making an IOS program that needs to access the API (raw POST, not UIWEBVIEW), but I don't know how to:

**A)** give the iphone a session id, and
**B)** send that session id to the server to access the API pages.

I assume this is what needs to be done to access API pages that require a sesssion/cookie...

Note: I did not use any CI session library - made my own. CI stores the sessions in a file cache, not the db.

Comment: CI can also store sessions in the database, you decide it in config file (the default is cookies though, anyway not "file cache")

Comment: What if storing in DB doesn't work for me. Is that a prereq to handle sessions for this use case?

Comment: No, I just corrected you on two wrong assumptions